# Using the a smartphone's speaker as a microphone

Tags: audio, hardware, microphone, speaker

I have a hardware accessing question. For a project, I was wondering if it would be possible to use the smartphone's speaker as a second microphone, similar to the idea that you can plug in a headset into your computer's audio jack and use it as a microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, as far as I am aware, there is no way to do this.

The speaker is highly ingrained into the hardware, and it would be highly difficult to get this to work - never mind that it could be impossible.

It *could* be possible, but it would require loads of hard work - including rewiring, and possibly some soldering - and your device may not survive.

Proceed at your own risk, but I would say that it isn't possible.

Comment: Impossible, if you ask me. Reason: While the speaker itself may produce (mediocre) voltage signals, it is still wired in this way **phone -> digital-analog-converter (DAC) -> amplifier -> speaker**. The DAC is output only just like a PC's line out. But you can't just reconnect it to a mic-in.

Comment: I too think that this is impossible (at least without some heavy hardware modifications).